# WooCommerce Critical error at order status change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am using this code to add admin action to change bulk order statuses.
I have custom build status with name "**wc-to-order**".
Unfortunatelly, I got error when use code from Woo bulk action.
Can anyone help me to resolve it?

This is code:

```
add_action( 'admin_action_wc-to-order', 'add_new_order_status_wc_on_hold' ); // admin_action_{action name}
function add_new_order_status_wc_on_hold() {
 
    // if an array with order IDs is not presented, exit the function
    if( !isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) && !is_array( $_REQUEST['post'] ) )
        return;
 
    foreach( $_REQUEST['post'] as $order_id ) {
 
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $order_note = 'That\'s what happened by bulk edit:';
        $order->update_status( 'wc-to-order', $order_note, true ); 
 
    }
 
    
    $location = add_query_arg( array(
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'wc-to-order' => 1, // markED_awaiting_shipment=1 is just the $_GET variable for notices
        'changed' => count( $_REQUEST['post'] ), // number of changed orders
        'ids' => join( $_REQUEST['post'], ',' ),
        'post_status' => 'all'
    ), 'edit.php' );
 
    wp_redirect( admin_url( $location ) );
    exit;
 
}
```

I got this in debug log

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in /public_html/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php:648
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log, it appears that $_REQUEST['post'] may not be an array. In the below code we first check if it is an array. If it is not, then we cast it as array.

```
add_action( 'admin_action_wc-to-order', 'add_new_order_status_wc_on_hold' ); // admin_action_{action name}
function add_new_order_status_wc_on_hold() {

// if an array with order IDs is not presented, exit the function
if( !isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) ) {
   return;
}
 
//check if it is an array. If not, cast it as array
$orders_array = is_array($_REQUEST['post']) ? $_REQUEST['post'] : array($_REQUEST['post']);

     foreach( $orders_array as $order_id ) {
 
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $order_note = 'That\'s what happened by bulk edit:';
        $order->update_status( 'wc-to-order', $order_note, true ); 
 
    }
 
    
    $location = add_query_arg( array(
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'wc-to-order' => 1, // markED_awaiting_shipment=1 is just the $_GET variable for notices
        'changed' => count( $orders_array ), // number of changed orders
        'ids' => join( $orders_array, ',' ),
        'post_status' => 'all'
    ), 'edit.php' );
 
    wp_redirect( admin_url( $location ) );
    exit;
 
}
```

This way we ensure that array is always provided to `join` function.